# Permission sets deployment isssue

Tags: deployment, permission-sets

I am trying to deploy Permission sets to Sandbox via Metadata API and I am getting the following error:

> permissionsets/Defer_Rules.permissionset -- Error: Permission DeferCalculations depends on permission(s): ViewRoles

I verified System Permissions for all profiles on both orgs and they are the same. I could not figure out the reason behind.

Comment: does your permission set include granting the user the ViewRoles permission?

Comment: sometimes these errors are VXX+1 to VXX issues wherein SFDC added new permissions into a preview sandbox but said permissions don't exist yet in PROD

Comment: @MarkPond This permission set is created to Defer Sharing Rules and I do not know what was changed as part of this change. All the information I have is deployment Zip file which is failing and does not specify a line number on the metadata file. Also, the migration is from Sandbox to Sandbox and Permission set exists on both sandboxes.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you enable the `DeferCalculations`, you also need to enable/check `ViewRoles` in the permission set: `'src/permissionsets/Defer_Rules.permissionset'`

Make sure its so, in both the source sandbox and target